# Custom pipe inside Async pipe

Tags: html, asynchronous, pipe, ionic3

I am trying to use a custom pipe inside the `ngFor` loop of async pipe in Ionic 3.

```
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let item of items | async" (click)="openItem(item)">
      <ion-thumbnail item-start>
          <img src={{item.avatar|changeAvatar}}>
      </ion-thumbnail>
      <p>{{item.name}}</p>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
```

This gives me the following error.

```
Error: Template parse errors:
The pipe 'changeAvatar' could not be found ("items | async" (click)="openItem(item)">
```

Am I doing somthing wrong?